# Nat type Strict, how to change it to Moderate or Open? Behind a router from my ISP

Tags: nat, isp

I'm having a Nat type strict, checked using the Xbox networking method on Win10 (Settings---Gaming---Xbox Networking).

Firstly, the problem I suspect, is I'm behind a router from my ISP. as my normal setup (ISP cable to my Wan port) I see the status page, and I have a Wan IP of 192.168.254.X I tried the following:

- Set the router as bridge mode (Give new lan IP same as ISP 192.168.254.X (before it was 192.168.0.X) and disable DHCP), still Nat strict.
- Set router as bridge mode (Give new lan IP and disable DHCP) and put laptop's IP as DMZ, still Nat strict.

Is the only solution left is to a buy static IP from ISP? and after buying one what should I do? call them? Sorry I never bought a static IP before.

Comment: Your ISP is probably doing Carrier-grade NAT. Why do you think you need a different type of NAT? You should still be able to join online games.

Comment: I want moderate or open because some games required it? Do I need to buy a public IP?

Comment: @azezEl - That is unclear.  You first should determine if your ISP is indeed using Carrier-grade NAT.  If the Xbox application never reported your network type as being open, and you have not enabled either port forwarding or UPnP, your actions alone would be enough even with a static IP address

Comment: @Ramhound - But I did the bridge mode and put the PC itself on DMZ, and I tried also UPnP, so it should have been open Nat at that point no? I am also sure the ISP is using Carrier-grade NAT because my Wan in the router is private 192 and traceroute is showing two private IP's. Am asking if buying a public IP would help.

Comment: If you are behind a Carrier-grade NAT then you will be unable to perform the actions necessary to have an Open NAT type.  You will have to get your ISP to assign you a static IP address before the actions you took will result in your NAT Type to be Open.  Contact your ISP

Answer (score 0):

Although Gamers are addicted to the idea of a perfect NAT type the amount of times it actually matters is minimal for two reasons.

1. Ipv6 is becoming widely adapted by isp and server hosts alike (IPV6 is a solution for the shortage of IP addresses which is the entire reason NAT/CGNAT even exists
2. Having a strict NAT type only allows you to connect to other Gamer's with an open NAT type which may be a win in itself (bare in mind this would only be the case if ipv6 wasn't available which is unlikely in itself)

You'll find most people have open NAT types that alongside the chance of a game not having IPV6 keeps the chances of issues low.

Make sure UPNP is on as this does help with connectivity  with double NAT/Strict NAT and finally if you're on Xbox in network they have a feature called Qos (Quality of service) this allows your xbox to create it's own rules about how packets are received.

Comment: Hi Connor, I am struggling to see an answer. Please note that this site is not a forum.  Its question and answers.